# Obtain newer version of NetSNMP for CentOS 5

Tags: centos5, snmp, rpm, net-snmp

I'm using CentOS 5. I have a need to use net-snmp version "net-snmp-utils-5.5-37.el6_2.1.x86_64" which is currently available in CentOS 6 but not in CentOS 5. The reason I need this version (or greater) is because there is a new supported option added to the config files that I need for my setup.

It would be very much appreciated if someone would give me some steps to install this version (or greater) on my production CentOS 5 systems. Upgrading to CentOS 6 is currently not an option.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: compile from source and install in /opt?

Comment: What is the best way to compile something from source without actual doing it on a production server? I'd rather not install the build tools on the servers. Thanks.

Comment: Boot into a development box running rhel5, install into /opt/netsnmp, then tar that directory tree, and copy to the production server

Comment: Thanks mike. How do I install into /opt/netsnmp on the dev box? Is that the prefix parameter to the "make install" command?

Comment: Iirc, it is as simple as './configure --prefix=/opt/netsnmp', make, make install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go to a RHEL5 development machine, untar the source of your choice, cd into the untarr'd directory then issue:

`./configure --prefix=/opt/netsnmp; make; make install`

Get some coffee :-).  Now tar the `/opt/netsnmp` directory up and copy to your production machine.  Be sure to either alias or otherwise prefer this new netsnmp.  If it won't run on the new box, `ldd` is your friend to track down which shared libs are missing.

Comment: I'm happy to assist... best of luck with your new snmp tools